# how to catch the files with an array using jade

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, pug

I'm using jade create html files but the thing is, when I try to put an array in a variable.jade file and I use interpolation `#{}` to catch the name of the .html and .jpg pictures files, it doesn't work at all. I have this: 
this is the variable:

```
-var paginas = ["inicio","nosotros","servicios","clientes","contacto"]
```

And I really want that my file searches into my .html files by an interpolation files with the names of the `-var` like this: 
This is the menu.jade files to create the menu of the website.

```
if pagina == 'inicio'
    li: a(href="index.html") #{pagina}
else
    li: a(href="#{pagina}.html") #{pagina}
```

of course I put the `-var paginaActual` (courrent page) to my .jade files in order to use them as a `-var` in other .jade files.

this is the same `if-else` but in the banner.jade file to put a banner in every website.

```
each imagen in paginas
if imagen == paginaActual
    img(src="img/#{imagen}.jpg" alt="#{imagen}")
```

The problem is, when I try to use this kind of interpolation, the `if-else` doesn't search into the files.html or .jpg and and never returns a good result.
Help me please 'cause I'm learning. thanks.